Beta sensitivity of the collector current
When biasing a BJT, I learned that the base resistor method is dependent on the beta value. This makes sense when calculating the collector current using the formula \$Ic = \beta \cdot I_b\$. However, when using the formula \$Ic = Is \cdot \exp(V_{be}/V_t)\$, the beta value disappears, and the dependency on beta isn't apparent.
Similarly, in the case of the base resistive divider method, if the collector current is calculated using the exponential equation, it seems understandable that there's no dependency on the beta value. But \$Ic = \beta \cdot I_b\$ should still hold true, making it seem like the collector current is dependent on beta again.
The equation \$Ic = \beta \cdot I_b\$ is a fundamental relationship for BJTs. Therefore, it seems like regardless of the biasing method, the collector current must inherently depend on the beta value.
Could you explain what I'm misunderstanding?


Additional: First of all, thank you sincerely for answering all my questions.
Then, why is the base resistor method dependent on beta, while the resistive divider method is less dependent on beta?
Also, it is an absolute fact that a BJT is a device that controls current through voltage.
However, the equation Ic equals beta times Ib still holds true, and this means that if the base current is fixed, using a BJT with a higher beta will result in a larger collector current (and vice versa).
This equation is always valid, so why does the beta dependency change depending on the biasing method (excluding emitter degeneration)? Honestly, I don’t fully understand this.

Note that beta is used through "variations" of ic and ib (beta=dic/dib), and not for static operation Ic/Ib.

Note also that Vbe is not equal to R2/(R1+R2)* Vcc in the case "biasing with resistive divider".

One thing to consider is that Vbe will be basically fixed to around 0.4-0.7V depending on the operating region selected for the transistor. The type of biasing you see in your circuit won't be used much without an emitter resistor that would allow the emitter to float to a voltage above ground. Another thing to consider is that in many practical applications, Ib is considered too small to matter much for calculating the DC bias resistors.

Is the question "no matter what biasing method I use, collector current will always depend on beta?"
If so, the answer is yes, but if you use negative feedback (like emitter degeneration, which is basically series-series feedback), then the beta dependency will be heavily reduced.

When analyzing mathematically, if the collector current in the base resistor method is calculated using the exponential equation, the beta term does not appear in the equation. This makes it seem as though the dependency on beta has disappeared, even though it is still actually dependent on beta.
Conversely, if the collector current in the voltage divider method is calculated using beta multiplied by the base current, it appears as though the collector current is dependent on beta, even though this method is actually less dependent on beta.

Additionally, I am unsure why the collector current is calculated using different methods in these two biasing techniques, Please exclude the consideration of emitter degeneration.

There's a difference between the saturation current \$I_S\$ as defined for a bipolar junction transistor model, and saturation current \$I_S\$ in the context of a diode. If the base-emitter junction is modelled as a diode, which obeys the diode equation, then the equation for base current through it, \$I_B\$, would be written:
$$ I_B = I_{ES}\left(e^{\frac{V}{\eta V_T}}-1 \right) $$
Here, \$I_{ES}\$ is the base-emitter junction's saturation current, as distinct from saturation current parameter \$I_S\$ used in transistor models. The two are related:
$$ I_S = \beta I_{ES} $$
Substituting \$I_{ES}\$ into your equation gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_C &\approx I_Se^{\frac{V}{V_T}} \\ \\
&\approx \beta I_{ES}e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}
\end{aligned}
$$
\$\beta\$ didn't disappear, it just got hidden, or encapsulated, inside the model's \$I_S\$ parameter, in the same way temperature \$T\$ is hidden inside \$V_T\$. I've expanded on this at the end, if you're interested.

Your first circuit calculates \$I_B\$ correctly, given the assumption that a diode develops \$V_{BE}\approx 0.7V\$. That assumption permits you to estimate base current with some accuracy. The second circuit though, which employs a resistor voltage divider to bias the transistor, is dubious, and not as trivial as it seems.
The base-emitter junction's "clamping" of \$V_{BE}\$ to a maximum near 0.7V means that the following claim is questionable:
$$ V_{BE} = V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$
It would be true if there were not a diode across R2, but there is a diode, the B-E junction. That diode will oppose (to some extent) any rise in voltage across R2 beyond 0.6V or so, so that last equation is therefore only true for:
$$ V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} < 0.6V $$
Above that threshold, you begin to get both base current and current through R2, which sum according to KCL, and the equation no longer accurately models circuit state. I don't see any analogue application in which this "divider" method of biasing is of any use. You might see this used in a digital/switching context, where there's no quiescent state to obtain and maintain.
The only way to obtain an accurate value for \$I_B\$ in the second circuit is to solve the set of simultaneous equations derived from applications of  KVL, KCL and Ohm's laws:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
$$ I_1 = I_2 + I_B $$
$$ I_1 = \frac{V_{CC} - V_B}{R_1} $$
$$ I_2 = \frac{V_B}{R_2} $$
$$ I_B = \frac{I_S}{\beta} e^{\frac{V_B}{V_T}} $$
I'll also add that both methods of biasing a BJT (for an analogue application) are bad, mainly because thermal voltage \$V_T\$ is temperature dependent, and collector current \$I_C\$ will vary significantly with even small variations in temperature.
Mostly you find that biasing is achieved via negative feedback, which can be done in many ways, such as a resistance between collector and base, or via emitter degeneration.

The diode equation:
$$ I = I_S\left(e^{\frac{V}{\eta V_T}}-1 \right) $$
The transistor's base-emitter junction is a diode, obeying that relationship. Compared to typical discrete diodes, B-E junctions tend to have very good "ideality", \$\eta =1\$.
I will replace \$I_S\$ in the standard diode equation with \$I_{ES}\$, in keeping with the convention used in this Wikipedia article about the BJT, indicating that it refers to the base-emitter junction's saturation current, as distinct from parameter \$I_S\$ in the transistor's simplified model.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_B &= I_{ES}\left(e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{\eta V_T}}-1 \right) \\ \\
I_C &= \beta I_B \\ \\
&= \beta I_{ES}\left(e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}-1 \right) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Thermal voltage is \$V_T\approx 25mV\$, and usually the transistor is operated with \$V_{BE}\$ far exceeding that, over 0.6V or so. Since \$V_{BE} >> V_T\$ we can make the approximation:
$$ e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}-1 \approx e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}} $$
The equation then becomes:
$$ I_C = \beta I_{ES}e^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}} $$
Encapsulate the term \$\beta I_{ES}\$ into a single parameter \$I_S\$ to obtain a scaled saturation current for use in simplified transistor models:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_S &= \beta I_{ES} \\ \\
I_C &= I_Se^{\frac{V_{BE}}{V_T}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Quote: "The equation Ic=β⋅Ib is a fundamental relationship for BJTs. Therefore, it seems like regardless of the biasing method, the collector current must inherently depend on the beta value.
Could you explain what I'm misunderstanding?"
Yes - there is a misunderstanding.
You are right, that the equation Ic=β⋅Ib is a fundamental relationship for a BJT.
However, you must not misinterpret this equation.
It just tells you that Ib is proportional to Ic (because Ib is a small part of Ic) but it does NOT tell you that Ic would be controlled resp. determined by Ib.
The current Ic is controlled by the voltage Vbe only (according to the well-known Shockley equation) and Ib is just a kind of by product (unwanted but unavoidable).
It is true that for some basic calculations the relation Ic=β⋅Ib can be used. However, there is not a single proof that Ic would be controlled by Ib. The working principle of all transistor-based circuits can be explained (and understood) using the voltage-controlled principle only.
Here is an illustrative example (proof) for voltage control:
The voltage gain of BJT-based amplifier stages depends on the transconductance gm (slope of the Ic=f(Vbe) curve) only. The base current determines the input of the stage. Because the actual gm value depends on Ic it is important to know and to stabilize the collector current Ic against uncertainties (B-tolerances) and temperature effects.
To answer your question in short (summary):
The collector current Ic is NOT sensitive to beta. When the bias point is fixed using a current that is "injected" into the base (instead of a voltage divider), it is still the voltage Vbe which is the dominant quantity (developped across the B-E-Path).
===================================
Here is what the great Barrie Gilbert wrote (PROCEEDINGS OF THE IEEE · SEPTEMBER 1999):
"Indeed, the modern view of the bipolar junction transistor (BJT) can afford to neglect its small base current (which is in no way a useful feature and is invariably just a troublemaker—another nonideality, like ohmic resistances and parasitic capacitances) and treat it as a pure transconductance (gm) element, in which the applied base-emitter voltage Vbe generates a precisely corresponding current Ic bearing an exponential relationship to this voltage: Ic=Isexp(Vbe/VT*".


when calculating the collector current using the formula \$I_c=\beta\cdot I_b\$ . However, when using the formula \$I_c = I_s\cdot exp(\frac{V_{be}}{V_T})\$, the beta value disappears, and the dependency on beta isn't apparent.

In the operating region where \$I_c \propto exp(\frac{V_{be}}{V_T})\$, \$I_b\$ is also \$\propto exp(\frac{V_{be}}{V_T})\$, and thus \$I_c \propto I_{be}\$. We simply define the ratio between these two quantities as \$\beta\$.
So the equation \$I_c=\beta\cdot I_b\$ doesn't really tell us anything above and beyond what the equations
\$I_c \approx I_s\cdot exp(\frac{V_{be}}{V_T})\$
\$I_b \approx I_{s(be)} \cdot exp(\frac{V_{be}}{V_T})\$
tell us.

The equation \$I_c=\beta\cdot I_b\$
is a fundamental relationship for BJTs.

Actually, this equation is only an approximation. \$\beta\$ is only approximately a constant. It's value varies depending upon operating conditions, such as temperature and \$V_{ce}\$. Further, it is a parameter that is generally not known with precision unless measured directly, as it's value (for given operating conditions) may vary quite a bit from device to device within the same manufacturing lot.
